# How to prevent override methods from being converted into final in R8?

Tags: android, proguard, final, android-r8, android-obfuscation

I am facing an issue while using R8 in my Android project. It seems that all the override methods in my code are automatically being converted into final methods. This behavior is causing problems as I need to override certain methods for customization purposes. Is there any way to avoid this conversion of override methods into final when using R8? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I looked at the R8 configuration files and instructions to see if there's a way to stop override methods from turning into final methods. I also tried different settings in my Android project, but I couldn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is tracked in https://issuetracker.google.com/329541426. Please check that for comments. A final answer might be derived from that later.